# Can't install tables on Python

Tags: python, pytables

I keep getting the error

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sv33cp8y\tables\
```

when trying to use

```
pip install tables
```

I've tried

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

and quite a few other things but still can't get it to work.

The full error that I'm getting is:

```
    Collecting tables
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/53/8f34ce887c2a2ad80518980419a5f6f41defc85a287a355987e559ce9385/tables-3.4.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    * Using Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
    * USE_PKGCONFIG: False
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5bjrxgs8\tables\setup.py", line 633, in <module>
    libraries=(package.library_name,))
  File "c:\python37\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 791, in has_function
    objects = self.compile([fname], include_dirs=include_dirs)
  File "c:\python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "c:\python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
    return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
    self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
    self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

   ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5bjrxgs8\tables\
```

I'm basically trying to convert a hdf5 file into a csv and I just can't get it to work or anything at the moment.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2990#issuecomment-333943013

Comment: Looks like you are getting an error determining the MSVC version. Version 14.0 is required. Is it installed? For what it's worth, I prefer the conda package manager and miniconda (or anaconda) suite of Python modules. conda does a very nice job managing the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a permission issue.

Try :

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Also refer to the discussion [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3884). Some folks had this problem with python version.

Comment: Hi, I tried that out and got the error: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.                  And the discussion was mainly talking about upgrading setup tools.

Comment: @ace10101 That's because this answer was made assuming you're on a Unix system